# How can I change focus between components

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I created A Jframe that consists of Jbutton (Ok),Jbutton(cancel) , Jtextfield and a Jtable .
I want when press on OK button , focus changes to Jtextfield, and when press a gain , focus change to JTable .

How can I change focus between Components ?

this what I have tried :

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            try{
                Robot robot = new Robot();
          
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
               }

            catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(testSoso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        }
```

it focus only on JTextfield  but does not change focus to JTable

edit: I also tried :

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent(JTable2);
```

but did not work

this is the whole code :

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Dell
 */
public class javaApp5 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form testSoso
     */
    public javaApp5() {
        initComponents();
        
      
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Ok");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("cancel");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 374, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(60, 60, 60))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 103, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(192, 192, 192))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 167, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
      //  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        //  jTable2.addRowSelectionInterval(0,0);
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
            
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(javaApp5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       // }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaApp5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaApp5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaApp5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(javaApp5.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new javaApp5().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Two statements are required: 1) one to request focus on the table and 2) the second to select the row/column. `Using a Robot is NOT the way to do this`. The answer in this question shows how to request focus on the table. The answer in your previous question shows how to set the focus on the row/column.

Answer (score 3):

When the user clicks on the ***OK*** button, keyboard focus is transferred to the button. Hence simulating pressing the TAB key via class `Robot` will transfer keyboard focus to the next component which is the *cancel* button.

Simply calling method [requestFocusInWindow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow()) worked for me. I added a boolean class member variable, named `txtFld`, in order to know which component needs to get the focus.

Here is my version of method `jButton1ActionPerformed`

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (txtFld) {
        jTable2.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    else {
        jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    txtFld = !txtFld;
}
```

No need for class `Robot` nor for class `KeyboardFocusManager`.

For completeness, here is your code with my changes.

```java
package javaapplication5;

public class javaApp5 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form testSoso
     */
    public javaApp5() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Ok");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{{null, null, null, null},
                               {null, null, null, null},
                               {null, null, null, null},
                               {null, null, null, null}},
                new String[]{"Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"}));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);
        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("cancel");
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout
                                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                        layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(jScrollPane2,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 374,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addGap(60, 60, 60))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                        layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(layout
                                                .createParallelGroup(
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                        false)
                                                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                                .addComponent(jButton1,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(jButton2,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 103,
                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                                .addGap(192, 192, 192)))));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(47, 47, 47)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        167, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(
                                        javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(
                                        javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (txtFld) {
            jTable2.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        else {
            jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        txtFld = !txtFld;
    }

    /**
     * @param args - the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code
        // (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default
         * look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                    .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // </editor-fold>
        // </editor-fold>
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new javaApp5().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private boolean txtFld;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

By the way, if you are learning [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), I recommend **not** using the GUI builder of your IDE.

Comment: thank you very much , I tried changes ,nothing happened ,even focus disappear :( 
@Abra

Comment: @CalmSea when `JTextField` gains keyboard focus, you see the flashing cursor. However, when `JTable` gains keyboard focus the GUI does not change at all. Hence when `JTable` gains keyboard focus it appears that the focus has _disappeared_. As you can see, I copied your exact code from your question and modified it. I tested it on Windows 10 with JDK 11.

Comment: The flashing curser does not appears on JTextField too :((
I do not Know what the problem is . I want a piece of code that make focus on jtable such as you press tab key . like when  first run the program , and press tab , focus will be on JTable , then press tab again , it moves to first cell, then second ... 
@Abra

Comment: I'm using JDK 17, netbeans 8.2

Comment: @CalmSea *The flashing curser does not appears on JTextField too* - using what code? Always test using the complete MRE provided by the person answering the question. When I use the code posted here, I DO see the caret flashing on the text field. If you want to see the focus change on the table then you can first click on a cell in the table (otherwise no cell is selected so there is nothing to focus on). Then click on the OK button and you will see the focus change from component to component. I'm running on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks to god , I finally found a solution to my problem ,  this what I did

KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().clearGlobalFocusOwner();
 for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
          
             try {
                 Robot robot = new Robot();
                 
                 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                 KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
                 }

@camickr

Comment: @CalmSea any solution that uses a Robot to change focus is a terrible solution. You have already been given a simple working solution. Not sure why you continue to ignore the simple suggestions given here and in your previous post.

Comment: Again ,because I want first row to be selected ,and focus on third cell , this solution make focus on jtable only , and previous solution select the first row but did not focus on third cell.  @camickr